Chinese Visa (M) for dual national of UK and Australia
I live in Kenya with a work visa on my British passport. I also have an Ausi passport but that has nothing to do with my status in Kenya.
I was planning on visiting China for the canton fair. I applied for a visa using the British passport. After the application, I realized that Australian's are exempt for 15days for certain Chinese visas.
Do you guys think there would be any issues going to China with both passports (UK+Ausi) with the pending visa application?

Pending application: should be ok. But I''m curious if your application will be rejected, could you use the Aussie privileges? (I do not think so, because rejection is about a person, not a passport, but let's see if somebody will add such case on an answer)

I still need to go to the visa application center to show the documents for the UK passport. no payments have been done either
was thinking if don't go to the center then the process won't go further and it'll stay in a pending state
